# Is there a Python equivalent of SQL age()?

Tags: python, timedelta

```
SELECT age('2014-07-24'::TIMESTAMP , '1984-06-26'::TIMESTAMP);
```

returns `"30 years 28 days"`

Timedelta isn't too comfortable to achieve this. Or maybe I'm wrong.

I got two dates and I want to diff them. The return of the function should be a string that contains the quantity of years, months and optionally days. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`dateutil`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import dateutil.relativedelta
>>> dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(datetime.datetime(2014,7,24),
                                         datetime.datetime(1984,6,26))
relativedelta(years=+30, days=+28)
>>> d = _
>>> d.years
30
>>> d.days
28
```